# Cannot send email through Alpine 2.02 (via Comcast) on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04

I can receive mail fine, just not send. my config in Alpine is as follows:

SMTP Server (for sending) =

smtp.comcast.net:587/tls/user=donaldjharrison@comcast.net

message displayed after typing ^x for send:

[Mail not sent: SMTP connection broken (command)].

I've tried different ports,removing tls, etc. to no avail.

HELP! :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be using the incorrect SMTP port.

Port 587 is usually used for plain SMTP [or STARTTLS].
Because you are wanting to use TLS, comcast lists port 465 instead.

Try changing your config line to:

```
smtp.comcast.net:465/tls/user=donaldjharrison@comcast.net
```